Determining the signature of a symmetric billinear form
Relevant Question:
Let $V:=\mathbb{R}^3$ and $s:V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the symmetric bilinear form:
$$s(x,y):=x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_2y_3+x_3y_2+x_3y_3$$
for $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3), y=(y_1,y_2,y_3) \in V$
Show that, $s$ is non-degenerate and prove that $s$ has the signature (2,1) through the investigation of:

Eigenvalues of the representative matrix (Number of positive/negative eigenvalues)
With Diagonalization
With Discriminant and definiteness

Relevant Completed work:
Showing that s is non-degenerate:
For $s(x,y)$ non-degenerate $\Leftrightarrow$ $(s(x,y)=0, \forall y\in V \implies x=0)$.
Let $s(x,y)=x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_2y_3+x_3y_2+x_3y_3=0, \forall y$
$\implies x_1y_2+x_2(y_1+y_3)+x_3(y_2+y_3)=0, \forall y$
$\implies x_1y_2=0 \forall y \in V \land x_2(y_1+y_3)=0 \forall y \in V \land x_3(y_2+y_3)=0, \forall y \in V$
$\implies x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)=0$
Calculating the representative matrix:
Take the standard basis of $V=\mathbb{R}^3$
$[V]_\beta= {(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}$ Let the elements of the basis be represented as $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$. Then the representative matrix of the bilinear form is:
$
  A= 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    s(\beta_1,\beta_1) & s(\beta_1,\beta_2) & s(\beta_1,\beta_3)\\
    s(\beta_2,\beta_1) & s(\beta_2,\beta_2) & s(\beta_2,\beta_3)\\
    s(\beta_3,\beta_1) & s(\beta_3,\beta_2) & s(\beta_3,\beta_3)
  \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
$
Calculation of the eigenvalues:
The characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$, $P_A=-\Lambda^3+\Lambda^2+2\Lambda-1$
Edited +1 to -1
You can calculate the signature by the number of positive/negative roots of this polynomial. It is however not factorisable but one can use descartes rule of signs to get that the signature is (2,1). However the eigenvalues are not whole numbers.
Relevant Doubts:

How do I diagonalize the matrix without the eigenvalues?
How do you use the discriminant and the definiteness to calculate the signature.


I don't understand your first question (How do I diagonalize the matrix without the eigenvalues?). Calculating the eigenvalues is part of the process of diagonalization. I agree with your method to find their signs, and I am sorry like you not to be able to calculate their exact values. Maybe "through the investigation of" only means: "try your prefered method among those three".

Typo? I found $P_A=-\Lambda^3+\Lambda^2+2\Lambda\color{red}-1$

@AnneBauval Yes there was a typo in the characteristic polynomial. It has been corrected now. Now regarding the question of the diagonalization of the matrix, that is exactly my issue the calculation of eigen values is part of the process of diagonalization so I am not sure how one is supposed to do it without it. I guess we will see how this resolves itself after the answer is graded.

What text are you using?  Frequently "diagonalization" means something rather different than what people think for bilinear forms, i.e. it refers to congruence not similarity so eigenvalues are optional.  Also what does the characteristic polynomial "is not factorisable" mean? Cardano's Formula should give you all 3 roots $\in\mathbb R$ which is your field.

The characteristic polynomial is
$$P_A(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)=-\lambda^3+\lambda^2+2\lambda\color{red}-1.$$
Since $A$ is a symmetric real matrix, it is diagonalizable, with real eigenvalues.

By Descartes rule of signs, or more elementarily because $\lim_{-\infty}P_A=+\infty$, $P_A(0)<0$ and $P_A(1)>0$, $P_A$ has exactly one negative eigenvalue, hence the signature is $(2,1)$.
An explicit diagonalization (which begins with a calculation of the three roots of $P_A$) is feasible but laborious and not enlightening. Maybe what they meant by diagonalization is rather the following:$$s(x,x)=2x_1x_2+2x_2x_3+x_3^2$$ $$=(x_3+x_2)^2-x_2^2+2x_1x_2$$ $$=(x_3+x_2)^2-(x_2-x_1)^2+x_1^2,$$ which proves that the signature is $(2,1)$.
The discriminant is negative (since $\det A=-1$), but $s$ is not definite negative (since $s((0,0,1),(0,0,1))=1$). I.e., the product of the three eigenvalues is negative, but some are positive. Therefore (again) the signature is $(2,1)$.



Yes that makes sense to me.



To be honest I still don't really understand what the discriminant is (The definition that we learnt was: "If s is non-degenerate, its discriminant is the equivalence class of the determinant A in the quotient group $\frac{K^x}{(K^x)^2}$. So in theory I understand that a negative determinant would imply a negative discriminant. But I am not sure how exactly that gives us information on the signature.


It tells you the sign of the product of the eigenvalues.
